# Get selected item in a list from view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

Good morning!

I'm programming a managment aplication that  shows a task list using WPF and MVVM patern. Users can edit this list too but I want to use a delete button to delete selected row. The problem is that I don't know how to access to the selected row from ModelView and I don't want to use code-behind. I guess the best option is using some binding but I'm unsure about how to do it.

This is the code ( I'm using DevXpress controls but is almost the same )

```
<dxg:GridControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TaskView}" Loaded="GridControl_Loaded">
       <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn Visible="False" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Project" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProjectCode, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowEditing="True" ContentChanged="OnHoursChanged"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Project Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProjectName, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowEditing="False"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProjectDescription, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowEditing="True"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Comment" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Comment, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowEditing="True"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="{Binding ElementName=mon,Path=Text}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=HoursMonday, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowEditing="True" FieldName="M" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="{Binding ElementName=tue,Path=Text}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=HoursTuesday, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowEditing="True" FieldName="T" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="{Binding ElementName=wed,Path=Text}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=HoursWednesday, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowEditing="True" FieldName="W" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="{Binding ElementName=thu,Path=Text}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=HoursThursday, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowEditing="True" FieldName="Th" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="{Binding ElementName=fri,Path=Text}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=HoursFriday, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowEditing="True" FieldName="F" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="{Binding ElementName=sat,Path=Text}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=HoursSaturday, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowEditing="True" FieldName="Sat" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="{Binding ElementName=sun,Path=Text}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=HoursSunday, Mode=TwoWay}" AllowEditing="True" FieldName="Sun" />
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Total" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Total, Mode=OneWay}" AllowEditing="False" FieldName="Tot" />
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your VM should have a `Project SelectedProject { get; set; }` property.

The bin the SelectedRow (or something) from the Grid to it:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TaskView}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedProject}"
```

Comment: Well is SelectedTask because a task has an associated project but is the same. But then how do I bind to this property in the XAML?

Comment: SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedProject}" is what i was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Oh wait!, it can't resolve SelectedItem.. it seems this property is not available ther

Comment: i assume there is no SelectedItem Property in the DevXpress GridControl. here is a alternative solution: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E1724.aspx . for the original wpf datagrid Henks solution works perfectly.

Comment: I should have said that I don't have telerik, I was guessing. No SelectedRow or similar? Odd.

Comment: Yes Henk, it's odd because you have to use something like <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView MultiSelectMode="Row" SelectedRowsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedTasks}" ShowAutoFilterRow="False" ShowTotalSummary="True" NavigationStyle="Row"/>
            </dxg:GridControl.View> but now is working pretty well and I can delete multiple rows. Thanks for the idea, though.Here's a very nice example about it http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E3139.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"  Margin="4,4,4,4"
                             Name="gridDatos"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Usuarios}" IsFilterEnabled="True"
                             >
                <dxg:GridControl.View>
                    <dxg:TableView AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" AllowEditing="False" NavigationStyle="Row"
                                   AllowHorizontalScrollingVirtualization="False"
                                   ShowGroupPanel="False"
                                   FocusedRow="{Binding SelectedUsuario, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="usuario_us" ReadOnly="True" Header="Usuario" Width="133" />
                    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="nombre_us"  ReadOnly="True" Header="Nombre" Width="308" />
                    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="activo_us"  ReadOnly="True" Header="Activo" />
                </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            </dxg:GridControl>
```